# OracleDataReader Read(); return false and System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I have done this manny times but now I get a error and I don't know how to fix it. The variables aren't null, they have value; I tried this in the DB and all is ok it return 1 row

```
List<Partido_E> lista = new List<Partido_E>();

try
{       
    conexion = bd.LeerDeBaseDeDatos();       
    orden = new OracleCommand(
        @"select * from partido 
          where TO_CHAR(fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = :anyo AND 
                equipo_l = :equipol AND 
                equipo_v = :equipov ", conexion);

    orden.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("anyo", fecha));
    orden.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("equipol", equipoL));
    orden.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("equipov", equipoV));
    orden.BindByName = true;

    lector = orden.ExecuteReader();

    while(lector.Read())
    {
        lista.Add(new Partido_E(lector.GetString(0),
                                lector.GetString(1), 
                                lector.GetDateTime(2),
                                lector.GetString(3),
                                lector.GetString(4),
                                lector.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : lector.GetInt32(5),
                                lector.IsDBNull(6) ? 0 : lector.GetInt32(6),
                                lector.IsDBNull(7) ? 0 : lector.GetInt32(7)
                 ));
    }


    lector.Close();
    lector.Dispose();
    orden.Dispose();

    bd.CerrarConexion();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error " + e.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

return lista;
```

Comment: You should prefer `WHERE fecha = :anyo` and `orden.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("anyo", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = fecha.Date;` (assuming `fecha` is a DateTime value rather than a string)

Comment: The fecha is string, isn't DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem - read comments

```
 while (lector.Read())
 {
      // if you never come here, your reader is closed
 }
 lector.Close(); // <-- problem here
```

Oracle:

> An OracleDataReader instance is constructed by a call to the ExecuteReader method of the OracleCommand object. **The only properties that can be accessed after the DataReader is closed or has been disposed, are IsClosed and RecordsAffected**.

This line `lector.Read()` can not throw null reference exception because line before that `lector = orden.ExecuteReader();` will always return reader. If no rows, it will be closed.

Your code is not wormed well. should be

```
using (conn = new connection/getconnection)
{
    using (cmd = new command)
    { 
        using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader)
        {
        } // no need to explicitly dispose/close here
    }
}
```